# Regression table for bayesglm?

Tags: r, stargazer, pander, bayesglm

[`stargazer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf) is a great tool to generate a regression table if you are not using [`bayesglm`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/arm/docs/bayesglm). For example, suppose I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(9782)
N<-1000
df1 <- data.frame(v1=sample(c(0,1),N,replace = T),
                  v2=sample(c(0,1),N,replace = T),
                  Treatment=sample(c("A", "B", "C"), N, replace = T),
                  noise=rnorm(N)) %>% 
  mutate(Y=0.5*v1-0.7*v2+2*I(Treatment=="B")+3*I(Treatment=="C")+noise)
```

I can run `lm` and then create html (or text) output for my r markdown:

```
lm(data = df1, formula = Y~Treatment+v1+v2) %>% 
  stargazer::stargazer(type="html", style = "qje")
```

Is there a way to do something similar for `bayesglm`? In this case, `pointEstimate` has the coefficients and `standardError` the standard errors

```
library(arm)
fit <- bayesglm(data = df1, formula = Y~Treatment+v1+v2)
posteriorDraws <- coef(sim(fit, n.sims=5000))
pointEstimate <- colMeans(posteriorDraws)
standardError <- apply(posteriorDraws, 2, sd)
```

Comment: bayesglm isnt in the list `?stargazer:::\`stargazer models\``

Comment: good lord, stargazer is [_a single function_](https://github.com/cran/stargazer/blob/master/R/stargazer-internal.R#L8), perhaps that's why no one has made an extension for bayesglm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this does the trick:

```
library(texreg)
htmlreg(fit)
```

and for text:

```
screenreg(list(fit))
```

Answer (score 1):

As @rawr points out in comments `stargazer` is -- while useful -- unfortunately written in a rather monolithic, hard-to-extend style.  The [broom package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=broom) is (IMO) a nicely designed modular/object-oriented framework for extracting summary information from a large range of model types, but it's not oriented toward producing textual/tabular summaries. For those who like that sort of thing, it would be great if the `stargazer` front end could be grafted onto a `broom` back end, but it would be a **lot** of work.  In the meantime, short of hacking the internal `stargazer:::.stargazer.wrap` function, this method (tricking `stargazer` into believing that `fit` is actually an `lm()` model) *sort of* works:

```
class(fit) <- c("glm","lm")
fit$call[1] <- quote(lm())
stargazer(fit)
```

It presents the coefficients and standard errors that are built into the `fit` object rather than the output of your posterior draws, but in this example at least those answers are extremely similar.

Comment: that's what I thought of doing but it didn't work--I didn't have the second line. I needed `quote(lm())` for this to work, though

Comment: yup. I ended up hacking through `.stargazer.wrap` until I found that stargazer is (ugh ugh ugh) using a special `model.identify()` function that looks at the call object as well as the class ...

Comment: Yeah, that's why ``texreg`` uses a generic function called ``extract``, so users can write and register their own methods. ``extract`` is built on a similar principle as ``broom``, though ``broom`` was developed later. The resulting ``texreg`` objects are S4 objects which store the relevant data like coefficients etc., and then the ``texreg``, ``htmlreg``, ``screenreg`` etc. functions can use those data to construct tables. You can either let the ``texreg`` function call ``extract`` internally, or you can save the intermediate results and manipulate them before you pass them on to ``texreg``.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with markdown, then the [generic `pander` S3 method](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#generic-pander-method) usually does a pretty good job:

```
> pander(fit, round = 4)

--------------------------------------------------------------
     &nbsp;        Estimate   Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|) 
----------------- ---------- ------------ --------- ----------
 **(Intercept)**    0.0864      0.0763      1.131     0.2581  

 **TreatmentB**     1.951       0.0826      23.62       0     

 **TreatmentC**     3.007       0.0802      37.49       0     

     **v1**         0.4555      0.0659      6.915       0     

     **v2**        -0.6845      0.0659     -10.39       0     
--------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Fitting generalized (gaussian/identity) linear model: Y ~ Treatment + v1 + v2
```

Please note that I forced the numbers to be rounded in this example, as some P values were extremely low, so the default `digits` and other [global options](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#general-options) would result in an extremely wide table. But there are some othe params you might want to use, eg:

```
> pander(summary(fit), round = 4, add.significance.stars = TRUE, move.intercept = TRUE, summary = TRUE, split.cells = Inf)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
     &nbsp;        Estimate   Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)         
----------------- ---------- ------------ --------- ---------- -------
 **TreatmentB**     1.951       0.0826      23.62       0       * * * 

 **TreatmentC**     3.007       0.0802      37.49       0       * * * 

     **v1**         0.4555      0.0659      6.915       0       * * * 

     **v2**        -0.6845      0.0659     -10.39       0       * * * 

 **(Intercept)**    0.0864      0.0763      1.131     0.2581          
----------------------------------------------------------------------


(Dispersion parameter for  gaussian  family taken to be  1.083267 )


-------------------- -----------------------------------
   Null deviance:     2803  on 999  degrees of freedom  

 Residual deviance:   1078  on 995  degrees of freedom  
-------------------- -----------------------------------
```